# Como traer la informacion de un select y enviarla a un form con PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Resulta que tengo una parte de la pagina que tiene un `select` con una lista de inquilinos que traigo de la base de datos en `phpmyadmin` y necesito que al hacer clic en el botón **Ver Inquilino**, agarre ese Inquilino que seleccione en el `select` y me traiga la información completa de ese inquilino que esta cargado en la tabla **web_inquilinos** y me la muestre en un modal que tengo con varios `input` (sería el mismo modal que uso para cargar un nuevo inquilino)

Este es el código donde tengo el `select` y el botón.

```
<div class="col-12 grid-margin">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form class="form-sample">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label style="margin-bottom:0.5rem;">Fecha de Alta</label>
              <div class="col-sm-4" style="width:30%;">
                <input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', date('d/m/Y')))); ?>" class="form-control" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 row">
          <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center">
              <a target="_blank" href="nueva_propiedad.php" style="width: 7.5em;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-nueva-propiedad"><i class="mdi mdi-home-plus" style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Nueva Propiedad</button></a>
              <?php
                // conecto a la db
                include('db.php');
                // consulto para obtener los datos de la tabla web_propiedades
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_propiedades";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                // Verificar si hay resultados
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  // Creo el elemento select y agrego los option
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:40.9%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["localidad"] . ", " . $row["direccion"] . "</option>";
                  }
                  echo "</select>";
                } else {
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:40.9%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  echo "<option value='0' disabled>No hay propiedades cargadas</option>";
                  echo "</select>";
                }
              ?>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino"><i class="mdi mdi-home-search" style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Ver Propiedad</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino" data-action="nuevo"><i class="mdi mdi-account-plus" style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Nuevo Inquilino</button>
              <?php
                // conecto a la db
                include('db.php');
                // consulto para obtener los datos de la tabla web_inquilinos
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_inquilinos";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                // Verificar si hay resultados
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // Creo el elemento select y agrego los option
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:45.3%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["apellido"] . ", " . $row["nombre"] . "</option>";
                  }
                  echo "</select>";
                } else {
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:45.3%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  echo "<option value='0' disabled>No hay inquilinos cargados</option>";
                  echo "</select>";
                }
              ?>
              <button type="button" id="btn-ver-inquilino" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino" data-action="ver"><i class="mdi mdi-account-search" style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Ver Inquilino</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cuando dices "select", te refieres a una Query o a un Select HTML?? Porque no se entiende si lo que ya tienes es una tabla con los "inquilinos" y solo quieres ver los detalles de este. Por otro lado phpmyadmin no es un gestor de Bases de Datos, estas usando MySQL??

Comment: @juan_fernandez para tal fin necesitas si o si javascript

Answer (score 0):

Aca te pongo un ejemplo de como debes hacerlo

```html
<div class="col-12 grid-margin">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-sample">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label style="margin-bottom:0.5rem;">Fecha de Alta</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4" style="width:30%;">
                                <input type="date"
                                    value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', date('d/m/Y')))); ?>"
                                    class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 row">
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center">
                            <a target="_blank" href="nueva_propiedad.php" style="width: 7.5em;"><button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-nueva-propiedad"><i class="mdi mdi-home-plus"
                                        style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Nueva Propiedad</button></a>
                            <?php
                // conecto a la db
                include('db.php');
                // consulto para obtener los datos de la tabla web_propiedades
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_propiedades";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                // Verificar si hay resultados
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  // Creo el elemento select y agrego los option
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:40.9%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["localidad"] . ", " . $row["direccion"] . "</option>";
                  }
                  echo "</select>";
                } else {
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:40.9%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  echo "<option value='0' disabled>No hay propiedades cargadas</option>";
                  echo "</select>";
                }
              ?>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino"><i class="mdi mdi-home-search"
                                    style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Ver Propiedad</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino" data-action="nuevo"><i class="mdi mdi-account-plus"
                                    style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Nuevo Inquilino</button>
                            <?php
                // conecto a la db
                include('db.php');
                // consulto para obtener los datos de la tabla web_inquilinos
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_inquilinos";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                // Verificar si hay resultados
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {




                /* comienzan los cambios que debes hacer */    

                 $web_inquilinos=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //creamos esta variable array unica, que nos sirva tanto en el php y el javascript


                echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:45.3%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                
                ##### IMPORTANTE DEBES CAMBIAR LA FORMA DEL BUCLE YA QUE fetch_all NO PERTENECE AL METODO OBJETO mysqli_result
                /// while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                foreach ($web_inquilinos as $row) {  
                    echo "<option value='" . $row["id"] . "'>" . $row["apellido"] . ", " . $row["nombre"] . "</option>";
                }

                /* fin de los cambios */




                  echo "</select>";
                } else {
                  echo "<select class='js-example-basic-multiple' id='select-inquilino' name='select-inquilino' style='width:45.3%;height:2.1em;margin:0 12px 0 10px; padding:0;'>";
                  echo "<option value='0' disabled>No hay inquilinos cargados</option>";
                  echo "</select>";
                }
              ?>
                            <button type="button" id="btn-ver-inquilino" class="btn btn-primary btn-nuevo-inqui"
                                data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#nuevo-inquilino" data-action="ver"><i
                                    class="mdi mdi-account-search" style="color: #fff;font-size: 13px;"></i>Ver
                                Inquilino</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<!-- CREAMOS EL SCRIPT JAVASCRIPT  -->
<script>
    const web_inquilinos = <?=json_encode($web_inquilinos,true)?>; //Obtenemos toda la consulta del php

    // addEventListener no entiende los id separados por guion, por ello hay que crear una constante legible para js
    // (trata de no usar esos guiones y en su lugar guion bajo _ )
    const seleccionado = document.getElementById('select-inquilino'); 
    const ver_inquilino = document.getElementById('btn-ver-inquilino');

    //escuchando el click del boton
    ver_inquilino.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //detenemos el envio del form que lo creaste pero no lo cerrastes

        //creamos un array en una variable => encontrado:  que sera un filtrado asociativo, reduciendo la matriz 
        let encontrado = web_inquilinos.filter(obj => obj.id == seleccionado.value).shift(); 
        //le indicamos que filtre por el id del array principal que haga match en el valor del select 

        console.log(`${encontrado.id} , ${encontrado.apellido} , ${encontrado.nombre}`);
        /*
        -- aca vas llenando los inputs del modal -- 
        Ejemplo 
        input_id.value = encontrado.id;
        input_apellido.value = encontrado.apellido;
        input_nombre.value = encontrado.nombre;
        */
         
        //LUEGO DISPARAS EL SHOW MODAL USANDO JAVASCRIPT TAMBIEN, EN LA PAGINA BOOTSTRAP TE INDICA COMO HACERLO
    });

</script>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda y punto de partida
Saludos